# Simulation of animation in javascript is slow

Tags: javascript, html, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to optimize traffic signal lights timings with genetic algorithm. I've made an animation of traffic in html5, and GA is implemented in javascript. So, when i want to run simulation of that animation, it runs forever.

Animation on every 20ms draw semaphores and cars, and updates values for next iteration. In simulation I only call update functions, because I don't need to draw semaphores and cars.

So the difference between animation and simulation is in that, that simulation doesn't draw anything on canvas and it runs in while loop, while animation runs in setInterval loop.

Any ideas how could I speed up simulation?

I tried to calculate travel time for each car, but its really hard because you need to include waiting times on red, in congestion etc.

Comment: Can you post some code or set up a JS Bin demo? And what do you mean by a "simulation of that animation"? Also, `setInterval` was never intended for animation - have you looked into `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: Depending on your code, maybe consider outsourcing the simulation to a [webworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_web_workers) and just send updates to the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly in the simulation you are running infinitely running code (or very long running code) in a while loop.

This is your problem. In languages like C++ and Java this is pretty normal practice because of multi-threading. While they are chewing on the code, other code can still run, the screen can still update...etc.

JS is a single thread. It is literally just gonna keep running that while loop and pretty much do nothing else, wrecking any smooth running of your program. Using while loops in this way is absolutely a "never do that" thing in single thread languages.